# bracket style border around elements

Tags: html, css, image, border

I'm looking for a way to implement a bracket style border around my `<h2>` headings; I've attached an image showing exactly what I'm trying to accomplish.

The only way I can think of to achieve this effect is by using images, but I'm unsure of exactly how to do so(all of my `<h2>`s are of varying length/height, or if maybe there is a better way.

Any tips & insight are greatly appreciated.

**I hate to resurrect this, but what can I look towards as being the solution to the problem shown int he updated image? The right line is too far right, as well as some opacity issues above and below the text..

[image: bracket borders]

UPDATE: [image: updated image]

Comment: Are the two lines supposed to be one <h2>? Is it acceptable to wrap them in one or multiple divs?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö Yes, the two lines of text are within one `<h2>`.
Any way that achieves the effect in the image is acceptable :)

Answer (score 2):

[Working jsFiddle example.](http://jsfiddle.net/9CHuH/1/)

Use the following. You just need to change the font of the text or replace it for an image, and maybe change the color of the borders to match yours.
For the HTML:

```
<div id="h2pre"></div>
<h2>
    <div id="h2inpre"></div>
    <div id="h2cont">Ready for the event of a lifetime?<br/>
    We'd love to hear from you.
    </div>
    <div id="h2inpos"></div>
</h2>​
```

For the CSS:

```
h2{
   text-align:center;  
   position:relative;    
   margin-left:50%;
   left:-150px
}

div{ float:left; }

#h2inpre, #h2inpos{
   background-color:#fff;
   height:50px;
   width:20px;
   border-bottom:1px solid #FFA500;
   border-top:1px solid #FFA500;
}

#h2inpre{
       border-left:1px solid #FFA500;   
}

#h2inpos{
     border-right:1px solid #FFA500;   
    clear:right;
}

#h2cont{
 font-family:"Arial",sans-serif;
 padding:5px;
 background-color:#fff;
}

#h2pre{
   height:1px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#FFA500;
    margin-top:25px;
    position:absolute;
    float:none;
}
```

​

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly possible. Take a look: http://tinkerbin.com/zQ1VWLLi

The HTML...

```
<h2 class="box">
  <span>Ready for the event of a lifetime? <br/> We'd love to hear from you.</span>
</h2>
```

The CSS...

```
h2:before,
h2 span:before,
h2 span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}

h2 {
  position: relative;
  font: 16px/1.2em cambria;
  text-align: center;
}

h2:before {
  top: 50%;
  height: 1px; width: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}

h2 span {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 7px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  background: /*same as background where it sits*/;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}

h2 span:before,
h2 span:after {
  left: 7%; right: 7%;
  height: 1px;
  background: /*same as background where it sits*/;
}

h2 span:before {
  top: -1px;
}

h2 span:after {
  bottom: -1px
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I've got it adjusted to my needs and working for the most part. However, I can seem to get the left(before?) line to show. Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/MXAKa/

Comment: I'll take a look in a few minutes.

Comment: Take a look. http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/MXAKa/4/ . The css is kind of messy, since I've tried to leave as much of your edits alone. If you show me the page where you'll have this inserted I'll reduce it to the smallest and cleanest css possible.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this, I really do appreciate it. 
Unfortunately, the site isn't live yet. Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z5a93/) with all of the relevant HTML & CSS. I'll also post an image in my original question to show what I'm seeing now- the brackets and lines are showing perfectly, but the lines are appearing much higher on the page than the brackets.

Comment: Take a look at the fiddle from my last comment. I solved that problem there. One question. Is this meant to be placed above an image background? Or is it to be placed above a solid color one?

Comment: So close to being perfect! The background is a small, repeated image. 
I'll update the image in my original post to reflect what I'm seeing now. The orange box is kind of faded in the center(I'm guessing should have 0 opacity?), as well as the right side line, which should be entirely opaque.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16852/discussion-between-joplomacedo-and-user1255049)

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<h2 class="bracket"><span class="text">Ready for the event of a lifetime?<br>We'd love to hear from you.</span></h2>
```

css:

```
.bracket {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #999;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
.bracket:before {/* vertical stripe */
  content: " ";
  border-top: solid 1px orange;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.bracket .text {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: .2em 1em;
  max-width: 80%;/* force that at least some of vertical stripe is still shown */
}

.bracket .text:before {/*left bracket*/
  content: " ";
  border: solid 1px orange;
  border-right: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .4em;
  right: 0;
}

.bracket .text:after {/*right bracket*/
  content: " ";
  border: solid 1px orange;
  border-left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .4em;
  right: 0;
}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ibiyal/2

You'll probably have to tinker with the padding of the text block, and the width of the left and right bracket.

Only downside is that it only works on a solid background.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with HTML and CSS.

### CSS

```
#container { 
   position: relative; 
   height: 43px; 
} 
#bracks { 
   background-color: #fff; 
   margin:0 auto; 
   border: 1px solid black; 
   width: 200px; 
   height: 40px; 
   position: relative; 
 }

#text { 
   background-color: #fff; 
   position: absolute; 
   width: 150; 
   left: 15; 
   height: 22px; 
   top: -1; 
   padding: 10px; 
   text-align: center;
 }

 #strike {  
   position: absolute; 
   top: 21; 
   width: 100%; 
   border-top: 1px solid black; 
 }
```

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="strike">&nbsp;</div>
  <div id="bracks">
    <div id="text">Some text here.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```